# Powerpoint - VBA - Slide status

Tags: vba, powerpoint, status

I hope you are doing well. 
I am a little stuck on a macro scripting, I would like to perform the following

1. Once the macro is launch ; create a form rectangle with attributes (see below)
2. If a rectangle already exist within the active slide the delete it.

Here is the little macro code written to insert the shape

```
Sub TBU()
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 902, 5, 47, 27)
With oSh
   With .TextFrame.TextRange
      .Text = "[TBU]"
       With .Font
        .name = "Arial"
        .Size = 12
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Underline = msoFalse
        .Shadow = msoFalse
        .Emboss = msoFalse
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .AutoRotateNumbers = msoFalse
        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
    End With

    With oSh
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .Fill.Solid
   End With
End With
End Sub
```

I tried to delete the shape within the active slide only if a rectangle with the same attributes already existed but got stuck on that.

Does anyone has an idea?

Kind regards,
Naxos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to find any shapes that you want to delete is to iterate over all the shapes in the current slide, and call a function that checks if the shape given matches your criteria.

It would look something like the code below. Basically, any one condition not matching is sufficient to say that the shape shouldn't be deleted. Therefore the function starts off by assuming that the shape should be deleted until it finds any condition that indicates otherwise, at which point it changes the return value to false and ceases checking for the given shape.

```
Dim i as Long
Dim sh as Shape
For i = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes.Count to 1 Step -1
    Set sh = ActiveWindow.View.Slide.Shapes(I)
    If ShouldBeDeleted(sh) Then
        sh.Delete
    End If
Next

'...

Function ShouldBeDeleted(sh as Shape) as Boolean
    ShouldBeDeleted = True

    'Repeat this IF structure for each criteria.
    If sh.Fill.Visible <> msoTrue Then
         ShouldBeDeleted = False
         Exit Function
    End If

    If Not sh.HasTextFrame Then
         ShouldBeDeleted = False
         Exit Function
    End If


    '... keep repeating these if structures.

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry, I had `True` and `False` mixed up when I first posted my answer. (It's corrected now.) Also, the support function could be done more elegantly with a bunch of conditions in one `If` statement, but VBA doesn't have short-circuiting on its Boolean operators, so I recommend just repeating the if statement structure.

Comment: I changed my answer from a For Each loop to a For loop that goes backward. The reason is that deleting elements of a collection (like a `ShapeRange`) will cause the VBA loop to skip elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very ingenious! Have a great evening